# Как сгенерировать массив, чтобы элементы генерировались в лекскикографическом порядке

Tags: java, алгоритм

Нужно сгенерировать что-то наподобие такого:

```
000
001
002
010
011
012
020
021
022
100
101
102
110
111
112
120
121
122
200
201
...
```

Мы должны указывать размерность массива и количество переменных для xj (0, 1, 2, ...).

Что есть:

```
int amountOfValuesX = 3;
int amountOfVariables = 3;
int[][] val = new int[amountOfVariables * 9][amountOfValuesX];
int[] vx = { 0, 1, 2 };
int indexForVX = 0;
int indexForVXPrev = 0;
int indexForVXPrevPrev = 0;
int counter = 0;
int cur = amountOfVariables - 1;
int prevCur = amountOfVariables - 2;
int prevprevCur = amountOfVariables - 3;
int indexes[] = new int[amountOfValuesX];
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfVariables * 9; i++) {
    if (i % 9 == 0 && i != 0) {
        indexForVXPrevPrev++;
        indexForVXPrev = 0;
        indexForVX = 0;
    }
    else if (i % amountOfValuesX == 0 && i != 0) {
        indexForVX = 0;
        indexForVXPrev++;
    }
    if (indexForVXPrev == amountOfVariables) {
        indexForVXPrev = 0;
    }
    val[i][cur] = vx[indexForVX++];
    val[i][prevCur] = vx[indexForVXPrev];
    val[i][prevprevCur] = vx[indexForVXPrevPrev];
}
```

Код работает, выводит результат, но как мне сделать для разных значений xj?

Comment: какой язык программирования ? и что такое xj?

Comment: java. Та тут впринципе без разницы, сам алгоритм нужен. Я сделал вывод, но он работает только для 3 елементов. Не могу сделать для больше.

Comment: xj это просто разные значения, которые может принимать x. В даном случае это 0,1,2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекурсией. Схематично так (пардон, в синтаксисах слаб):

```
proc generate(alphabet[],current,length) {
  int i;
  if length=0 {
    output current;
  }
  else {
    for (i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++) {
      call generate(alphabet[],current+alphabet[i],length-1);
    }
  }
}

call generate('012','',3);
```

Само собой, alphabet[] должен содержать массив символов в лексикографическом порядке.

Схема допускает в т.ч. генерацию наборов, если для каждого знакоместа свой алфавит. Тогда массив алфавитов будет двумерным, плюс добавится массив длин алфавитов, если они различны.

Comment: Благодарю! Все работает))))

Comment: @OlegVitiuk если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте принять его (галочка слева от ответа). Ну и заодно посмотрите мой вариант, хотя бы чтобы знать про альтернативы.

Answer (score 0):

Генерация массива вариантов с заданными алфавитом и количеством символов и в порядке согласно алфавиту. Без использования рекурсии.

Идея состоит в том, чтобы по порядковому номеру "числа" (`i`) определять его цифры.

```
private static int[][] create(int[] alphabet, int symbolsCount)
{
    int combinationsCount = pow(alphabet.length, symbolsCount);
    int[][] numbers = new int[combinationsCount][symbolsCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < combinationsCount; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = new int[symbolsCount];
        for (int j = 0; j < symbolsCount; j++)
        {
            int delimiter = pow(alphabet.length, symbolsCount - j - 1);
            int position = floor(1.0 * i / delimiter) % alphabet.length;
            numbers[i][j] = alphabet[position];
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}

private static int pow(int number, int exponent)
{
    return floor(Math.pow(number, exponent));
}

private static int floor(double number)
{
    return (int)(number + 0.0001);
}
```